# как добавить поле в ответ запроса

Tags: javascript, typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

начал разбираться в RTK query и не понимаю как в ответ на мой запрос добавить ещё одно поле

```
export const postAPI = createApi({
    reducerPath: 'postAPI',
    baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({baseUrl: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com'}),
    endpoints: (build) => ({
        fetchAllPosts: build.query<IPost[], number>({
            query: (page:number) => ({
                url: `/posts?_limit=25&_page=${page}`
                //параметр page приходит из элемента 
            }),

        }),
    })
})

export const fetchPosts = createAsyncThunk(
    'post/fetchAll',
    async (_, thunkAPI) => {
        try {
            const response = await axios.get<IPost[]>('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
     //        здесь приходит ответ в формате interface IPost{
     //                                                         userId: number,
     //                                                         id: number,
     //                                                         title: string,
     //                                                         body: string
     //                                                       }
     //  куда нужно вставить поле page из PostAPI, как провернуть такое?
            return response.data;
        } catch (e: any) {
            return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(e.message)
        }
    }
)
```

в слайсы такую логику засовывать не стал, он же должен быть чистой функцией